# does mongodb have any compiled list of non compatible functions on sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb

does mongodb have any compiled list of non compatible functions on sharded cluster? 
I was looking for a compile list of non compatible functions on sharded clusters, so we can anticipate the changes can be made on sharded clusters eg. db.collection.renameCollection() is not supported on sharded collections. You cannot rename views.
So if there are other functions that we can anticipate that will not be used on sharded cluster that will be helpful.